# Tag synonym request: [library] -> [libraries]

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Tag synonym request: [library]->[libraries]](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/3724/tag-synonym-request-library-libraries)

[library](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/library) and [libraries](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/libraries) seem to be used exactly the same way. Perhaps one of them was once meant to relate to the use of Ubuntu in [libraries of the non-computing sense](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Library), but if so, then with [just one notable exception](https://askubuntu.com/questions/146146/how-to-configure-ubuntu-for-public-kiosk-use), that's not how either tag is used in practice.

I'm not sure which tag should be the canonical one, but [libraries](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/libraries) has a few more questions, so I suggest that [library](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/library) be made the synonym targeting it.

I cannot [suggest the synonym here](https://askubuntu.com/tags/libraries/synonyms) because I don't have a high enough answer score in the tag. Perhaps someone else can suggest it.

Comment: Yes. Please synonymize each other!

Comment: Discussion about this has been [rekindled here](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/3724/tag-synonym-request-library-libraries), so I recommend actually making this older question a duplicate of that newer one.