# Tag synonym request: [library]->[libraries]

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed, tag-synonyms

[library](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/library) has 15 posts, and [libraries](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/libraries) also has 15 posts. They should be merged into [libraries](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/libraries), as both tags have fairly similar questions about missing libaries.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, I think so. Both tag should be merged without delay. They have similar questions about the missing libraries. And the master tag should be [libraries](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/libraries).